# how to parse XML attributes with poEdit?

Tags: xml, internationalization, poedit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [poedit and xml files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307612/poedit-and-xml-files)

This subject was already addressed in [poedit and xml files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3307612/947026) but my question is a little more specific. I know that poEdit can parse several languages and extract text strings. XML is not natively supported but it can be handled by adding a dedicated parser. Which I've tried to do, following instructions in the thread mentioned above.

My problem is that poEdit will only recognize strings that are nested in tags.

Ex:`<label>This will be recognized</label>`

I would like poEdit to recognize value attributes

Ex: `<DataUI datatype="TEXT" value="My text string"></DataUI>`

Does anybody know what kind of keyword I could type in poEdit settings to catch the "My text string" part?

Thanks!!!