# Poedit doesn't recognise my *.xml files

Tags: xml, poedit, po

I configured Poedit (1.8.7 on OS X 10.11) according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307612/poedit-and-xml-files), but get the this message:

"warning: file 'xyz.xml' extension 'xml' is unknown, will try C"

But my configuration is as follows:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it’s a terribly misguided idea to use the *Glade* extractor to extract anything other than *Glade* files — your custom XML file isn’t.

I’m guessing that this particular error is a side-effect of changes in gettext-0.19.7 that introduced support for custom XML files via [ITS rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Preparing-ITS-Rules.html#Preparing-ITS-Rules) and implemented Glade support in terms of it. I think (but again, am not sure) that it simply ignores the `-L` flag in this case.

The best way to do this is to

1. Add a custom extractor with your extension, specifying standard gettext invocation, *without* the `-L glade` lie.
2. [Write ITS rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Preparing-ITS-Rules.html#Preparing-ITS-Rules) for your file format.
3. Put them in the location of other `.its` and `.loc` files in Poedit’s installation.

Comment: The xml (xhtml) files we use in our application have a one-on-one link to a PHP file; each xml file is managed by a PHP file. I wrote a custom syntax handler for gettext translations like this: <p> {\_translated text\_} </p>. Our framework reads that and hands it over to the gettext php function. As I understand it now, I do not need ITS files in that case. I just need to add a custom extractor for these xml files. Is that correct?